# Rails3 ":popup has been deprecated"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

EDIT: I have accidentally awarded a bounty of 500 points for this question - please do not answer it as I did this without realising what was going on - yes I'm an idiot

In rails 2.3.x, the following code would open a link in a popup window:

```
= link_to "resource", resource_path(resource), :popup => true
```

But in Rails 3 I get the error message: `DEPRECATION WARNING: :popup has been deprecated.`  I'm guessing that this is to do with the drive to keep JS unobtrusive.  Anyone know how to fix this? I'm using prototype...

PS - In case it makes a difference, I don't actually use `:popup => true`, instead I have:

```
:popup => ['new_window', 'status=0,toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0,directories=0,resizable=0,scrollbars=0,height=550,width=480']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fixed this using prototype-legacy-helper plugin and link_to_function with a javascript method found [here](http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/1770)

Comment: The link is dead. Do you have any other references/links to the plugin? Is this the same one? https://github.com/rails/prototype_legacy_helper

Answer (score 0):

And so it should be, this is a move in the Rails 3 framework towards unobtrusive javascript, if you wish to continue using popups, write your own javascript.